# Delay and Manually initialize mdl materialLayout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, material-design-lite

Strange bug.....

- I have a race condition where my angularJS directives for `header` and `drawer` are compiling *after* material-design-lite initializes the layout.
- It only seems to happen when I shut my wifi off and work offline. No remote resources are required, though google tag manager, and facebook connect plugin fail in the network tab.

**Questions**:

1. Can I delay MDL's automatic initialization (which I see happens `onload` of the page?
2. Can I manually reinitialize the mdl-layout so that it properly constructs the drawer button, etc., all over again?
3. Does anyone have any idea why being offline would cause any rendering/javascript issues?

I have already tried `window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` but that doesn't reinitialize the layout

Comment: why not just `componentHandler.upgradeElement(document.body)` when your angular has fully commited the DOM to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem in case anyone else runs into this (mdl race condition with angular):

1. Load the material.js library once the header directive has loaded
2. wait for `window.componentHandler`
3. Then run `window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`

Full code (placed in header directive)

```
function materialize(){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'assets/js/material.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        (function upgrade(){
            if (!window.componentHandler){
                return $timeout(upgrade, 200);
            }
            $timeout(window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered);
        })();
}
```

Comment: CHAMP!! same problem with SharePoint